# Why is R Markdown finding awesomeIcons as an error?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I've made an interactive map in R and am trying to publish it so that I can add it to a website. Below is the code:

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
library(RCurl)
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Homes_In_Trust <- file.choose(new = TRUE)
Homes <- read.csv(Homes_In_Trust, header = TRUE)

icons <- awesomeIcons(icon = "home", iconColor = "blue", markerColor = "orange")

Minneapolis <- leaflet(Homes) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addAwesomeMarkers(lng = ~lon, lat = ~lat, popup = paste("Address: ", Homes$Address, "<br>",
                                                   "Beds/Baths: ", Homes$Bed, "<br>",
                                                   "Square Feet: ", Homes$Footage, "<br>",
                                                   "Initial Closing Year: ", Homes$Year, "<br>",
                                                   "Developer: ", Homes$Developer, "<br>",
                                                   "Type of Home: ", Homes$Type, "<br>",
                                                   "Neighborhood: ", Homes$Neighborhood, "<br>",
                                                   "Market Rate Price (At Closing): ", Homes$Market, "<br>",
                                                   "CLCLT Price (At Closing): ", Homes$CLCLT, "<br>"),
                    icon = icons)
Minneapolis
```

I sent this to R Markdown, saved it, and am trying to publish it to EPubs, but need to knit it to HTML first.  However, when I knit it, I get the following error:

```
processing file: Interactive.Rmd
Quitting from lines 18-35 (Interactive.Rmd) 
Error in awesomeIcons(icon = "home", iconColor = "blue", markerColor = "orange") : 
  could not find function "awesomeIcons"
Calls: <Anonymous> ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval

Execution halted
```

Why would it find an error in awesomeIcons? AwesomeIcons is just part of leaflet isn't it? So I'd assume it should run easily.

Comment: What version of `leaflet` do you have installed?

Comment: I have leaflet_2.0.2

Comment: I've just tried running it without the awesomeIcons bit to see what happens, and it also sees an error in addAwesomeMarkers because it can't read lon. lon is one of the variables/columns from the .csv that is being read, so could it be a problem with reading the .csv?